# Can I safely uninstall older versions of Python after upgrading?

Tags: python, versions

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14 and I see I have a number of Python folders .... Python 2.7 and so on up to Python 3.4 .  Do I need to leave all the older ones alone or can they be deleted? I see that somebody uninstalled 2.7 and now they are having problems.

Comment: Yes, the binaries that depend on python are version specific

Comment: Just to add, i mistakenly uninstalled python once, and a huge chunk of the system got unistalled with it. Had to reinstall Ubuntu. So don't play around with those

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there are only 3 versions of Python in Ubuntu 14.04 repository: 2.7, 3.3, 3.4

- Almost all applications use v2.7 , so I could say it: noway to remove it.
- v3.3 not used (only if you are a developer), could be removed no harm.
- v3.4 few applications start using it as alternative (they keep 2.7 compatibility), could be removed but check if it will suggest removing other packages.

It is possible to check their reverse dependencies, using `apt-cache` to get better idea:

```
apt-cache rdepends python2.7
apt-cache rdepends python3.3
apt-cache rdepends python3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the packages that need python to run are version specific, as python2.x is very different than python3.x:

http://www.slideshare.net/pablito56/python-2-vs-python-3

There is an effort to migrate all the packages of Ubuntu to Python 3 since ubuntu 12.10 and also its not allowed new packages using Python 2.

Python 2 is only maintained for provide support to legacy apps.

Fonts:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/FoundationsQPythonVersions

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3